# What effect does the weight function have in the stratified population mean formula?

Tags: mean, stratification

The stratified population mean formula is $\bar{X}=\sum_{h=1}^HW_h\bar{X}_h$, where $W_h=\frac{N_h}{N}$ is called a weight function. Can someone explain intuitively what affect this weight function has on the population mean?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have any effect on the **population mean** $\bar{X} = \dfrac{1}{N} \underset{k \in U}{\sum} x_k$.

But what it means is that if you used stratified sampling, you put different selection probabilities on your units. Thus, the **sample mean** $\bar{x} = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k \in s} x_k$ is no longer an unbiased estimator of $\bar{X}$.

$\sum_{h=1}^{H} \dfrac{N_h}{N} \bar{X_h}$ is an unbiased estimator of the population mean. Intuitively, using $W_h = \dfrac{N_h}{N}$ means that units with higher selection probabilities have lower weights, because they represent a lower number of units than the ones with lower selection probabilities.